# Why did Hitler hate Jews?

Tags: jews, hitler

why hitler and his Nazis and germans hates the Jews, Why hitler has provoked people to hate (if he really provokes) jews. And why did he spend lot of time and money to kill the jews instead of doing war ?

And why did he put Halocaust is most proiority in his agenda ?

I did some research on this but I did not find any clue on this, even hitler did not mention any dislike or hateing of jews in his autobiographhy `mein kampf`.

I found some artcles answered on this but every article is reffreing to Hitler likes Aryan Race only shoul live, then if that is the case ? why does he particularly hates Jews ? why he dont hate other races ?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9476/what-was-hitlers-attitude-towards-the-aryans-of-india/10362#10362). Although its not exactly an answer to your question. But it is too wide and not easily answered in anything less than a chapter at least.

Comment: Try reading *Mein Kampf*. Hitler gives many reasons, none of which hold any water of course.

Comment: If this question was cleaned up, it might be worth answering providing decent source material can be found. In practice explaining the cultural origins of Europeans pogroms and other proto-Holocaust behaviour is neither quick nor easy answer. Separating the window dressing of Nazi propaganda from their underlying sentiments isn't easy; so you could just easily reword the question as _"What reasons did the Nazis provide for their anti-Semitism?"_

Comment: @Semaphore - The problem there is that the only answer with any upvotes doesn't address this question at all.

Comment: Because hating Jews is something everyone in Germany could agree on at the time.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom how are you not blocked yet?